# Uploading image to Strapi /upload with axios and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, strapi

Let me start by saying, that I know there are a lot of duplicates, but either something has changed with Strapi or I'm missing something obvious.

Strapi Version: v3.4.6

The goal is to upload an image or .zip file through the /upload endpoint (or any other custom endpoint if it makes life easier). This is what I have now:

The input element:

```
<input
   type="file"
   name="files"
   onChange={ this.handleVPNUploadChange }
   id="icon-button-file"
/>
```

The handler:

```
handleVPNUploadChange(event) {
  console.log( "handleVPNUploadChange", event.target.files[0])
  this.setState({
    uploadedFile: event.target.files[0]
  })
}
```

The request:

```
let formData = new FormData()

formData.append('files', uploadedFile);
console.log(uploadedFile)               //check image below
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); //check image below
} 

axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: baseUrl + 'upload',
   data: formData,
   headers: {}
})
```

[image]

Before you start shouting that I forgot to add the `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` header, please note that I tried that and got this 500 error on the Strapi end: `bad content-type header, no multipart boundary`.
Then I read somewhere, that if you never add the `Content-Type` header in the first place, it will be automagically generated with the boundary.

The current error I am getting is this:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I’m on Strapi V4 and also bouncing between 400 error and 500 error with the same scenarios you’ve listed. I’ve tried with fetch() and axios and postman and it’s always the same

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```js
const imgFile = event.target.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', imgFile, imgFile.name);

axios.post(url, formData).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log(error.message);
});
```