# I am getting 'files are empty' with a 400 code

Tags: reactjs, node.js, arrays, rest, graphql

I am trying to upload images to strapi, what am I doing wrong here? am I putting the `fileArrayForUpload` in the wrong place? the `fileArrayForUpload` is not empty.

handleCreateSubmit:

```
 const [createProduct] = useMutation(CREATE_PRODUCT);

   const handleCreateSubmit = useCallback(async () => {

      const res = await HTTP_CLIENT.post('/api/upload', fileArrayForUpload);
      console.log(res);
      await createProduct({
         variables: {
            data: {
               reference: reference,
               description: description,
               price: {
                  displayPrice: currency,
                  numericPrice: numericPrice,
               },
               category: selectedCategory,
            },
         },
         onCompleted: handleSucessSubmit,
         onError: handleErrorSubmit,
      });
   }, [
      reference,
      description,
      currency,
      numericPrice,
      selectedCategory,
      fileArrayForUpload,
   ]);
```

My input code:

```
 <input
                  ref={inputRef}
                  accept="image/*"
                  type="file"
                  multiple
                  id="select-image"
                  style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                     if (!e.target.files) return;
                     const selectedFiles = Array.from(e.target.files);
                     const dataUrls = selectedFiles.map((file) =>
                        URL.createObjectURL(file),
                     );
                     setFileArrayForUpload(Array.from(e.target.files));
                     console.log(fileArrayForUpload);
                     setImageUrlArray((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...dataUrls]);
                  }}
               />
               <label htmlFor="select-image">
                  <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
                     <FileUploadIcon fontSize="large" />
                  </IconButton>
               </label>
```

I expect the images to be uploaded but i'm receiving error 400 "Files are empty" and it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need enclose the files in a form format when uploading them.

```
const imgFile = event.target.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', imgFile, imgFile.name);

axios.post(url, formData).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

[Uploading image to Strapi /upload with axios and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886539/uploading-image-to-strapi-upload-with-axios-and-react)

You can check the network payload in your web browser when uploading files in the admin panel
[image]